# Make sticky div function responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to figure out how to turn off the sticky ability for my div when my site begins to scale to a specific size (767px). I tried changing the the position from absolute to relative in a media query. But when I tried to scroll past the div the whole screen scrolls back up to the div instead of allowing me to scroll down.

How can I remove the sticky effect when I scale to 767px and enable it when I scale to 768 and above?

```
$(function() {

    var $sidebar   = $("#postRecipe"), 
        $window    = $(window),
        offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
        topPadding = 15;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        } else {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }
    });    
 });
```

The CSS

```
 #postRecipe {
     position:absolute; 
     float:left;
     width:30%;  
 }

 #content {
     float:right;
     width:50%; 
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y8KGG/4/

Comment: What do you mean by 'sticky ability'?

Comment: when you scroll down the div begins to stick/scroll down to where you are in the site @ckersch

Comment: Try putting each of your articles in its own div. You can set the heights of the divs and have them scroll separately.

Comment: That won't work with what I an trying to do. What I need to do is have the div postRecipe stop scrolling when the browser window begins to scale to a width of 767px. Leaving the div on top of the content (removing the sticky/scrolling effect the postRecipe div @ckersch

Comment: Because you move the content from the flow, there is no space where the original content was and it moves.

Comment: I may of not explained what I need correctly. Everything works the way it needs to work. Expect when I begin to scale the browser I would like the ability for my "sticky" div to stop moving/scrolling at a specific screen width down when I scroll and allow the div to be a static div on top of my content @epascarello

Comment: AH, I read it as the content was shifting. So add a check in the code for screen width before setting it to "fixed".

Comment: I am sorry I may of explained in wrong. I did that within a media query and it works until I begin to scroll. What is happening is when I scroll past the div postRecipe, it is causing the page to scroll back to postRecipe on its own instead of allowing me to scroll to see the rest of the content on the site @epascarello

Comment: Add a width check so the scroll code is ignored. Is there a reason you will not do that?

Comment: I can not figure out how to do that, that is exactly what I am trying to do  @epascarello

Comment: `if($(window).width()<767){ return; }` or on window resize set a flag that says if it is wide or not. `$(window).on("resize", function() { isWide = $(window).width()>767 }).trigger("resize");` and in the code check for isWide's state

Comment: where would I add that into my code? I tried it and the same effect still seems to be happening @epascarello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following test is the one that activate the sticky effect:

`if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) { }`

You can add a condition to activate it on specific screen sizes.
For example, you can activite it only on screen that have a width of 767px minimum:

`if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top && $window.width() > 767) { }`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tzi/y8KGG/16/)

Answer (score 1):

I have messed with something in jfiddle.  You have to clean it up but I am sure you can use this to reference what you are doing.

I ran the JavaScript only when the screen was at a certain resolution.  In firefox which I am using it works but doesn't change by simply making your screen smaller you have to refresh the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/y8KGG/10/

The JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    if ($(window).width() >= 500) {
        var $sidebar = $("#postRecipe"),
            $window = $(window),
            offset = $sidebar.offset(),
            topPadding = 15;
        $window.scroll(function () {
            if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                $sidebar.stop().animate({
                    marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                });
            } else {
                $sidebar.stop().animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The CSS

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    #postRecipe {
        position: relative;
        float:left;
        width:30%;
    }
}
#content {
    float:right;
    width:50%;
}
#postRecipe {
    position: absolute;
    float:left;
    width:30%;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Fixed the problem by calling the function every time the window is re sized.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y8KGG/17/

New JS:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    var $sidebar = $("#postRecipe"),
        $window = $(window),
        offset = $sidebar.offset(),
        topPadding = 15;
    if ($(window).width() >= 500) {
        $window.scroll(function () {
            if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                $sidebar.stop().animate({
                    marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                });
            } else {
                $sidebar.stop().animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: this is exactly what I am looking for but I can't have it only work when you refresh the page. Thank you though @KevinZaki

Comment: No problem.  I would have fixed the rest but ran out of time.  Thinking about it, you would just have to set that IF statement I added in the JavaScript to listen every time the window size is changed.  That should fix your problem.

Comment: ok I will play around with it. Thank you for your help @KevinZaki

Comment: Figured I might as well update and give you the full answer I edited my post.  Check as answered if it is what you wanted.